# time-based temporary authentication

Tags: users

Is anyone aware of a time-based rather than one-time login authentication module for Drupal?

We've discovered a problem where some email servers with advanced security tools will crawl through emails to verify the links in them. In so doing -- they invalidate the one-time login links, preventing some users from using them. Rather than verify on whether the link was clicked once, I want to invalidate it based on time. For example -- the link to login is valid for 1 hr from when it was generated.

Comment: This sounds like a security issue waiting to happen. I think your best bet is to figure out why the advanced security tools are doing this and work to comply with them by making sure your emails pass through unmolested.

Answer (score 0):

In Drupal 7 you can do something like the following:

Set `user_password_reset_timeout` variable (i.e. in settings.php
i.e. in settings.php:

```
$conf['user_password_reset_timeout'] = '600000';
```

Then it will use this time after password generation link, when this much time elapsed the link will be invalidated.

You can follow the thread [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/246029)